# Discrete amplifier not passing audio

Tags: voltage, amplifier, audio, grounding, decoupling-capacitor

I have a card that can receive two dual input opamp with feedback. The card is currently connected to V+ and V- only for taking measurements. The +24V rail is doing great. I also know for sure that both opamps are in good working order. One of them has received a full recaping job a few days ago. The receiving motherboard has also been fully recaped today.

When I connect the input and output audio cables I have no audio coming through (well very very low level grainy and distorted bits of audio).

I took a few measurements and some values are on the low side, while one of the pins gives me voltage where it shouldn't. The measurements are exactly the same for both opamps.

The measurements are as follows:

6 = 23.3V

5 = 12,2V

3 = 0V

1 = slowly dropping from 7V (instead of 0V)

7 = 8,9V (instead of 12V)

2 = 10,5V (instead of 12V)

I am attaching a few documents to help you understand the circuit better.

What would be your ideas? I can take measurements and replace faulty components but I must admit that I am not too at ease with that kind of opamp with feedback and decoupling..

Thank you!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Current setup (10k stereo pot at the bottom, output summing card at the top) :
[image]

Comment: At the very least this needs a schematic showing how you are testing it, what you are connecting externally.

Comment: Hi, nothing connected except V+ and V- when measuring the voltages. (contrary to what the photo shows). The PSU has V- grounded to the chassis.

Comment: Then you aren't connecting an audio input?

Comment: Not when measuring the voltages on the pins.

Comment: When the audio was poor, how were the inputs and FB used

Comment: Was this "Neve Card" replaced into it's original surrounding circuitry, or are you attempting to use it in a different application?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It was used like on the picture: white wire is audio in from a 10K pot, red wire is ground from the same pot. Green wire is a floating ground in a pigtail, blue wire is out to another amp card's input.

Comment: @rdtsc Hi, it is used in a genuine Neve design: input transformer > 10k input pot > this card with the opamps > output amp card with every channel summed into one > output transformer. It was custom made in the 70's so no schematics have survived unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, that is one funny op-amp.  Are the red-black-blue supply wires +12V, 0V, -12V?  Make sure the other boards are getting the correct power. I'd suggest using a multimeter to check this board's yellow tantalum caps for shorts, then the transistors as two diodes each, then the resistor values.

Comment: This is not an "op-amp" in any sense of which I am familiar.

Comment: @Wizzardzz Is the feedback pin 7? That diagram is very fuzzy. But that seems the only possibility.

Comment: Are you certain the card the op amps are plugged into is good?

Comment: @Hearth That's the question I was leading to. If pin 7 is the feedback pin and it is supplying such an incorrect voltage then this process halts until we have more context than we now have. Can't be helped further until more of the surrounding situation is in view. The NFB is critical to interpreting the rest.

Comment: @Hearth Yes one was entirely rebuilt yesterday. Tried 7 other ones coming from a working environnement with exactly the same voltages measurements which led me to believe the issue is not coming from the opamps..

Comment: So to be completely clear, you think the problem is on the board and not the op amps?

Comment: @jonk Please tell me exacly what you need and I will edit my post. A basic schematic of the full circuit maybe?

Comment: @Hearth Yes I believe so

Comment: _"7 = 8,9V (instead of 12V)"_ - according to my calculations it _should_ be 8.9V (unless overdriven by something on pin 2). Exactly what did you have connected to pins 1 and 2 when taking the measurements? What is normally connected to these pins (please show its schematic)? Does the polarity of C1 match the known good boards?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm assuming for now that TR1 is being used as a difference amplifier with (-) and (+) inputs and that the feedback is coming in, via R5, to what amounts to the (-) input. But nothing is shown in the schematic for circuitry driving that feedback. By this, I mean, that the feedback line shown there is an *input* to this circuit and not an *output* from it. It should be driven from outside of what we can see. The problem is that we don't see what's driving it. Do you think it is supposed to be an output? If so, I need to reexamine what I'm thinking here.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks for chiming in Bruce. It's good news if the voltage seems correct to you. I just plugged everything again (please check the pcb picture I posted for wire colors): output from 10k pot to white wire, ground from 10k pot to red wire, green wire to ground, blue wire to output (that's the cabling that was originally in the unit). I am getting a tiny bit of audio on the right slot (even if I change the opamp for another one). Still nothing in the left slot of the card.

Comment: @Wizzardzz It's my assumption for now that the feedback line is an input to *this* circuit coming from circuitry that lays elsewhere beyond my view and generates it as an *output*. If that's right, I'd like to see that circuitry. Especially since an error there would definitely cause this circuit to move to unexpected quiescent values. But if I'm wrong, then I need to spend more than a cursory glance and I should be ignored, for now.

Comment: @jonk I added a picture of the surrounding circuitry to my post. Nothing more than this is connected to and from the opamp card.

Comment: @Wizzardzz Pin 2 must not be DC grounded ( AC ground may be ok but input impedance is low and source impedance might affect gain, also  your schematics have no wire colours.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks a lot Tony, what should pin 2 be connected to? It's indeed going to V- at the moment through a resistor and a capacitor. Should I leave it unconnected?

Comment: @Wizzardzz The picture is nice just to see the entire system. But the little "stages" there that we are discussing are part of a larger context. I'm assuming that there is a more serious power amplifier out there and that there is feedback coming in from it and backwards towards the feedback like of these little stages. If there is a power-amplifier section problem, then the feedback may very well be incorrect and if so then there is no good way to relate expected voltages in the stage to measured. The feedback can place the stage "out of kilter," if it's not right.

Comment: @jonk There is no other power amplifier in the system. The full circuit is as follows: XLR input > input transformer > 10K input gain pot > opamp > output amp with 10k gain pot > output transformer > output XLR. My unacademic ">" mark wire connections between each element. I don't know if that helps. When I bypass the opamp block and connect the input gain pot to the output amp it works like a charm.

Comment: @Wizzardzz I'm reading what you are saying. Then I'm looking at the schematic, again, and at TR1 in particular. That feedback line goes to something. It's not hanging in the wind. Is it just hanging there for no apparent reason? (And I do accept the "no power amp" given that TR4 and TR5 are 1 W BJTs. I had thought it might be a power pre-amp output with a later, larger power amp. But I'm taking your point on this and dumping my prior uncertainty.)

Comment: @jonk Would the opamp work if the feedback is not used? I feel like IN- being grounded through a resistor and capacitor and the FEEDBACK pin being left hanging was intentionally made (which is why the PCB was design with holes to receive components to that IN- pin to 0V).

Comment: @Wizzardzz Could be. I've not spent enough time on the circuit, yet. Just finished with my regular work. All I could do is skim and recognize a few bits. (Such as that TR1 is being used as if this circuit were designed when transistors were expensive.) When I catch up on some other things now, I may get a moment to think a little more and flesh out my thinking.

Comment: @Wizzardzz I just spent about a half hour considering the DC quiescent operating point part of it. It is unusual. TR5+R11+R12+R13 just make up a 7 mA constant current sink. R1+R2+R3+C2 make up a VREF of about +8.5 V with a little more than 50 k Ohm source impedance to the base of TR1. C3 is a miller cap. D1 keeps TR4 out of saturation (where I suspect it really wants badly to be.) Looks like R9 sets about 1 mA as the collector current for TR3. TR1 exponentially converts small signal diff into collector current, magnified by TR2's beta, and R6 converts all that transconductance to a voltage.

Comment: @jonk That technical components explanation is very instructive, thanks a ton! That's heavy research material for me to better understand electronics there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The card is currently connected to V+ and V- only for taking measurements...
> I took a few measurements and some values are on the low side, while
> one of the pins gives me voltage where it shouldn't...

> 1 = slowly dropping from 7V (instead of 0V)

This is expected. Pin 1 is connected to the Base of TR1 via a 10 μF capacitor. If power has been switched off for a long time the capacitor will be discharged and have 0 V across it, so the initial voltage measured with a meter will equal the bias voltage on TR1 Base (~8,2 V). As the capacitor charges up through the meter's internal resistance a voltage will develop across it, reducing the meter voltage. Digital multimeters typically have a resistance of 10 MΩ when reading DC volts, which would cause the measured voltage to drop to 7 V in ~15 seconds.

Readings taken after power has been switched of for a 'short' time could start at a lower voltage because the capacitor is already partially charged. When the 10 kΩ 'gain' pot is connected to the input the capacitor will charge much faster and the meter will almost immediately read 0 V.

> 7 = 8,9V (instead of 12V)
>
> 2 = 10,5V (instead of 12V)

I simulated your circuit in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html). It calculated 10.6 V on pin 7 and 8.9 V on pin 2. There is no reason for pin 2 to be a higher voltage than pin 7, so I suspect you have the values swapped and the actual voltages are as expected.

> The measurements are exactly the same for both opamps.

This strongly suggests there is nothing wrong with the 'opamps'. The DC voltages are also normal, so something else must be causing the weak distorted audio.

In the comments you say:-

> The full circuit is as follows: XLR input > input transformer > 10K
> input gain pot > opamp > output amp with 10k gain pot > output
> transformer > output XLR.

and

> I just plugged everything again (please check the pcb picture I posted
> for wire colors): **output from 10k pot to white wire**, ground from 10k
> pot to red wire, green wire to ground, **blue wire to output**

Your module pinout diagram shows input on pin 1 and output on pin 5, but the actual wiring has the white wire on pin 5 and blue wire on pin 1. So if your description is correct then you are feeding the input from the pot to the amplifier output, and taking the output from the amplifier input - in other words **you have it wired backwards**. In this 'reverse transfer mode' very little if any signal will get through, and it could be severely distorted as the amp fights against it.

Comment: Thank you very much for that logical and efficient explanation. It all makes sense now regarding the pinout and the schematics. Most importantly it works like a charm!

Comment: Another user mentioned removing the connection to V- from pin 2 (connected through a resistor and a capacitor on the card). Does that make sense to you also? I can't understand why these components were implemented on the card, both the resistors and capacitors are new so I guess whoever messed up the wiring also added these components wrongfully? Thanks!

Comment: The components going from pin 2 to ground set the gain. They were probably installed at the factory. Without them the amplifier would have a gain of 1 = 0dB, ie. it wouldn't provide _any_ amplification!

Comment: Yes @BruceAbbott but the supply must also use a floating ground due to the DC bias

Answer (score 1):

Grounding -ve input to Vee=0V disables it.

You can use a differential input to Vin+ and Vin- but ONLY if the DC gnds and supplies are floating with respect to each other.  Otherwise do not! Also do not put a cap across the Vin- to the rail. That will destabilize the internal feedback and it may oscillate. You can't AC ground the Vin+ and use Vin- either. This amp or the source must be "floating" and no use of SMPS either.

There are other methods, but this will work with 4 stages of gain being up 80 dB open loop with at least 20dB to 30 dB of AC/DC internal feedback.

It is a high gain low impedance current limited with fixed gain without Feedback added to reduce the gain but the internal 12V reference for the output and inverting input so and inputs and outputs must be AC coupled, but not Vin- which is low input impedance.  **That must be direct-coupled in differential mode to the inputs provided, yet floating.  The input cap provided is to decouple from the inverting input ( the emitter) not isolate from the source.**

**The input level must be on the order of 1 mV and up and the source impedance determines the gain down to ohms for max gain!!**  So padding the source might be necessary for a large signal to a very low input impedance (< 8 Ohms for max gain) but I suspect <1K source impedance for reasonable gain is what it was designed for. *( I wonder what the user's manual says)*

The lack of current sources everywhere with only 5 transistors relies on the high supply voltage for reducing the current modulation. So the output swing will likely be only a few volts max which is pretty loud for a headset.

Reducing the internal R feedback with the external FB connection to Output will reduce the gain very little (?).  The feedback goes to the emitter so that attenuates the feedback with low impedance already, but current limited so it is intended for Sennheisers with high impedance. = 300  ohms not 8 ohms.  With
that load, I expect it should be high-quality THD ~ 0.1%

It is not your typical Op Amp design. "It's a NEVE"

- ***Your Voltage measurements are normal, but a more detailed explanation is needed to explain why) See my simulation for more accurate results***

[here is an accurate simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2CMBWAbAJgSOkVwBwoCwCcAzIUmAOxjH4XEjkbpJIgICmAtHHAFAAuIYghQY4o-MVE9REOCE6FIcfCjxhUeOFO1QEhMuLTE4dcjhwYYIACbsAZgEMArgBt%20AthVZxCokZa%20shgKSlJI6tQ4hBpIdFBItChgBkimIuH4VhB2Tm4egnCMBBDJliXgCvIUkAg0%20Cw8YKrE1ApgtQj4OPBIUjgIKcTEgda5Lu68AO4gZRjes2DlBODTi%20XI60LNqwBOW61Zc8LBKFRga2RCIgc3FwBKIFcnIN3XwRD4EN%20VHQhraB8CzmplYFxmVzegNegTWh1mK3hoNmvEekMsnwxlS%20syyPz%20nmOO2h8LkVWIkAiQ2EFBUYGSwz0dS%20MTOLBwSEGFGytgcEw8%20xGR02QtmFkqKGS4NuohJdwBIpuklELwu%202VT1YGreEGQF0E3QgVwCmsq3AwKCwODoGjoOAa9Mk7UpkpwxDiFDORTg9P8OT5%20TWJpkbDU8x8QbDbxNPVWM2DCwQ4nDcdmmze2oxa0zocsOsjecsCAW%20fVUjFefLqrY5FgQYWLxNquzVZuTfl%20yuFWedwtdc7rDm6IlUrVGGKOK7OLkdYAxuPSjiiqUlr9oLB5Jw-l1ulJqGARChCPg8eu%20DNl2mfBPvgDV8jL8iUArWC8SclU9C1BtB5tpdDEivGEMBfMQVRuENiF4fYAOFHxk0%20c4x2hZEkQWCAKEGMc0Nfe0UwwrDeHnOYv02aE5C4H1yUpHoSBpOkGXoDoYHPIDSPg6RoNzd5uLmORBhbWVxVFb9U1FVC8K-OFJJFD9yOko5hLk8ULnnPcKyEOS-wwSjSlqE9rRGYtKBobAoBYwSNI1cRLCgmwYTkEtYy7Xk8kmGZDRTcSFlYzzIXLK4x2LHw-C8LUsR9fswowULgp4iB1F4bB5HwIoFHLTzOHLMkemsXyu1XJNpHQ3gADcNM4KFxU4WMyUi75oEQbp0HxWog2TZFPORC5km5R8fMYFQsiyTgAB0AGcAEkADsksoCry1EjKQFGgAHCaZrm7lRJq0pqpDEaNtm3qFy2GytiyNajq27YjhWM5ZRWLIADV7AAIxu91LG4V93SqLUQFej6TqIQdV1B3FPkBgB7ZwPBOl5RReVKAaBm6UfSiQ0qh57YY8ecMayrHWEUMFzI3C1lC%20RAkBiBBi2IWluWY%20BeAAc1eNLuCjctuBPX4uMJ87CcC7YLlWzmSYy2M0pS1YJfUyrbI-XaQjxAFqreRX8whQdJzB8oiK2VW5j5vFyfkJBoAobw0miaIyDSC24RV2Mdtqridqq77sqEVpeGhtgjkqbR9AaV4GvkOQA4YQhZmxDlB1qKB5FTmOyJD4QSAxa2cHEFrlHjvgRhrEAADEo-Jg89CqEAAFlHAADwm3H3EcNn2F4EueHLyv0BWc1W-4dvO6AA) of how to use the amplifier with a low impedance floating differential source and thus high gain.

You can add series source resistance (using thumbwheel over the 330 R source R) and experiment with observing the ratio of output to input gain with the output Vpp probe.

The schematic uses **labelled Nodes** to connect the inputs.  Here the input is 1mVpp and the output is 2.134 Vpp with a clean undistorted gain of 2134.  Vfb is left open.
[image]

Vfb (pin 7) is at a midpoint for constant current DC Voltage between Pin 2 (Vin-) and Pin 5 (O/P)  but that ratio does not define unity gain. Rather the ratio of (R15+R4/ (Rsource/hFE)) emitter low input impedance defines the gain with both R5+R14 for AC feedback and DC self bias.

Comment: Thanks Tony! It makes a lot of sense. The opamps were wired backwards. I was stuck on using the wiring originally present in the unit (which I did not try before dissmantling it for cleaning). That wiring was wrong.

I will leave pin 2 floating by your recommendation. I have tried it by removing the resistor and capacitor and it works very well.

Comment: I will take some time trying to figure out that feedback connection to try and understand how to use it as FB & IN- pins are both unused now.

Comment: You misunderstand. If Pin 2 is not connected the high impedance promotes no gain.  The supply  grounds must be isolated or floating and Vin- is that AC differential ground but common mode foating.

Comment: USE floating supplies BUT connect inputs to both Vin+ and Vin- from ground for best performance and use a 300 ohm headset.  Got it?  Then you can use a guitar pickup or other low impedance source at mV levels

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit your post with additional information. It all makes sense now!